# I want help in calling below Stored procedure into my MVC model

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have this stored procedure written in SQL Server.

```
USE [AppMarketplace]
GO


SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspTerms] 
@ID int

AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

if(exists(select * from AppmarketApp where ID= @ID)) -- checking whether user exists in main user table

BEGIN
 if(exists(select * from AppTerms where ID = @ID)) -- if exists in the main table then check in terms table for accepting condition

BEGIN
return 1; -- if user has accepeted terms and condition
End

else
Begin
return 0; --if user not accepetd terms and codition
end
end

begin 
return -1; --if user doesnt exists in AppmarketApp table
end
end

GO
```

Now I have to call this in my MVC Model.I am using EF Database first approach. My first question is

1) Do i need to call SP in Model or controller? explanation with
    code would be better.

2) And also I am looking for code to this scenario : I need to write
    logic to check whether user accepted terms and condition. If user
    not accepted terms then I should display terms and condition page
    and force them to accept. How it exactly works is first I will check
    my Appterms table.In this table I have two fields called ID and
    Date.If user accept terms then date when user accepted will be
    stored in this table with thier ID. So if datefield is empty for
    userID it means they have not accepeted terms and conditon..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) Do i need to call SP in Model or controller? explanation with code would be better.

Neither, your stored procedure call should be in your business logic layer.  The controller is really a presentation layer and should only deal getting data and passing it onto your view.

Your model or ViewModel should not have any business logic tied up in it either, it should really be a DTO.

Comment: Hi it may sounds dumb question but how do i create business logic layer? Is it same as model??

Comment: Have a look at this article on Onion architecture http://www.develop.com/onionarchitecture Your service layer is where you would keep your business logic.

Answer (score 0):

There are some detailed tutorials on asp.net web site. You didn't mentioned what approach you use for database connection, so if you are using ADO.Net model read following:

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef/the-entity-framework-and-aspnet-getting-started-part-7

If you use Code First you have to call SP manually:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/advanced-entity-framework-scenarios-for-an-mvc-web-application

Comment: I am using EF Database first approach.